# JQuery extract string multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML that is in a JavaScript string variable I'd like to extract into an array the values 1234, 5678, 9012 using JQuery:

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="1234"/>
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="5678"/>
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="9012"/>
```

I've tried various reg expressions, but I'm having trouble looping or `$each` round the string to find all the `values="xxxx"`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but ID's should be unique.

Comment: You can not have the same id on multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not use duplicate `id`'s more than once.

Use a class, then grab the elements using `$('.class').each();

```
var elements = [];
$('.classname').each(function() {
    elements.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's inside a string you can simply use `$(<string-value>)` to turn it into a jQuery object and then use the `.filter()` function to iterate over the input elements:

```
var str = '<input type="hidden" id="name" value="1234"/>\
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="5678"/>\
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="9012"/>',
values = [];

$(str).filter('input').each(function() {
    values.push(this.value);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ebiqaz/1/)

Comment: that might be a tad excessive for what he is trying to do

Comment: @BarryChapman OP stated there's HTML in a string; this should do exactly that :)

Comment: oops, i completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: IDs ***MUST*** be unique.

But here is how you can go about it:

```
var arr=[];
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/XNhas/

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '<input type="hidden" id="name" value="1234"/><input type="hidden" id="name" value="5678"/><input type="hidden" id="name" value="9012"/>';

var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = html;
var inputs = temp.getElementsByTagName('input');
var values = [];
for (var i=0; i< inputs.length; i++)
{
    if(inputs[i].type == 'hidden'){
        values.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
};
alert(values.join(','));
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/NSZEV/)

Comment: Thanks guys, the string contains the same id names as it's returned from an Ajax call, the string is returned in the response. The response string contains several templates. Besides rendering the templates I have to get the values which are then processed separately. Hope that clears the multiple ids being the same

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to them for easier selecting.

Until that, you can try something like this:

```
 var results = []
 $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
  results.push($(this).val())
 })
```

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu Just so you know, I didn't downvote you, so no need to be childish & downvote my answer. However, you ***still*** have a syntax error.

Comment: I don't downvote for typos or other trivial things, like some people do

Comment: @Dom look harder, having a downvote in my rep mean I received that downvote. So not sure who's rushing here.